# Next 14 Routing and Url manipulation

Tags: next.js

I have a search component that displays some posts. When i hit search it is rendering a search route with posts matching a search params. Now problem that my url path is "http://localhost:3000/search?s=as", and i have project to rebuild that uses for example this path "http://localhost:3000/?s=as". As you can see i have to eject a search from url , but still be able to display a search route.

I have fixed this on post categories in nextConfig like this:

```
const nextConfig = {
  async rewrites() {
   return [
     {
       source: "/:slug",
       destination: "/category/sport/:slug",
     },
   ];
 },
};
```

Not working for a search route and I also tried some other rewrites in next config but none of them were doing the thing.

Here is a Search Component

```
"use client";
 import { useRouter, useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
 import { useState } from "react";
 import navStyles from "../../css/nav/nav.module.css";

 const SearchBar: React.FC = () => {
 const router: any = useRouter();
 const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");
 const searchParams = useSearchParams();

 const handleSearch = async () => {
   const params = new URLSearchParams(searchParams);
   if (searchQuery) {
     params.set("s", searchQuery);
   } else {
     params.delete("s");
   }

   try {
     await router.push(
       `/search/?s=${encodeURIComponent(searchQuery)}`           
     );
   } catch (error: any) {
     console.error("Error navigating to search:", error.message);
   }
 };

 const handleKeyPress = (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
   if (e.key === "Enter") {
  handleSearch();
   }
 };

 return (
   <div className={navStyles.searchStyle}>
     <input
       type="text"
       placeholder="Search..."
       value={searchQuery}
       onChange={(e) => setSearchQuery(e.target.value)}
       onKeyDown={handleKeyPress}
     />
   </div>
 );
};
```

export default SearchBar;

Comment: I don't understand. Please explain what you want to do and not what you do. You want do do search? You want to do this? https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/adding-search-and-pagination

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `usePathname` in `next/navigation`.

Comment: Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem.